# Tomcat commits abnormal amount of virtal memory and dosen't release it

Tags: java, tomcat, memory, memory-management, jvm

issue:
java commits big amount of virtual memory AND DOESN'T release it.Then server goes down. But java(tomcat) consumes normal amount of memory. For example real heap is 1gb, but commited virtaul memory is 30g...
parametrs for old config: min/max heap - 512m/2048m, tread stack size 512kb, perm 64m, max perm 256m

Server status now:
Physical memory:

> 16383.55 MB Available memory: 4917.84 MB Total page file: 47103.55 MB Free page file: 34961.65 MB Memory load: 69  Process kernel time:
>   1701.58 s Process user time: 9451.538 s
>
> PS Eden Space Heap memory 129.00 MB 509.50 MB 634.50 MB 467.03 MB
>   (73%)  PS Old Gen Heap memory 341.50 MB 1064.00 MB 1365.00 MB 884.52
>   MB (64%)  PS Survivor Space Heap memory 21.00 MB 9.00 MB 9.00 MB 0.00
>   MB (0%)  Code Cache Non-heap memory 2.43 MB 21.75 MB 48.00 MB 21.50 MB
>   (44%)  PS Perm Gen Non-heap memory 64.00 MB 178.50 MB 256.00 MB 178.47
>   MB (69%)

what i have:

> - windows server 2012r2,
> - 4vCPUs,
> - 16GB of ram (was 2vCPU and 8GB of ram)
> - Apache Tomcat/7.0.56
> - JVM 1.7.0_72-b14
> - application server for DAM with few sites, less than 200 users
> - Virtaul memory size is defined by policy and set to be managed by a system (sounds like joke but has ~45gb...)

what i did:
i was trying to reconfigure server changing GC settings, agrresive heap, heap sizes etc. without any result.

what do you need:
like screens, heap dump, GC logs?

thank you in advance, i will be waiting for all suggestions!
Best regards,
DB

Answer (score 0):

Most internal hotspot data structures assume that they can work on contiguous amounts of address space, so they *reserve* that amount in advance. That does not mean they *commit* that memory. This is to ensure that no random allocations will happen in those address ranges.

Generally the individual regions (heap, metaspace, code cache...) will not reserve more than the maximum specified by their command line options. You can inspect them by appending `-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal` to your actual configuration.

Some of those default maximum values are calculated based on available physical ram.

If this is a problem - it shouldn't be unless you disabled overcommit in your kernel (well, thata's a linux-thing anyway) - you can use [native memory tracking](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr007.html) to see which block reserves that much and restrict by lowering its upper bound.

If it doesn't show up in NMT the next likely candidates would be a native library or direct byte buffers/memory-mapped files that somehow aren't released.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for answer! I have printed all flag and seems to be ok (as was defined for jre). What i can observate now is that tomcat process uses 12GB of phisical RAM, 20GB are commited (virtual memory) but heap has not more than 1.5GB of ram usage. Also fine thing present in linux is disabling virtual memory but windows doesn't have it... can it be issue related to tomcat holding of sessions (like dead sessions present and are not removed)? - because it what i can found looking on system usage right now... I will be waiting for your reply! Thak you ina dvance